# Referencing a SELECT list jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select

I have a SELECT list as follows

```
<select id="LIST">
   <option value="1">New York</option>
   <option value="2">Chicago</option>
   <option value="3">Miami</option>
       .
       .
       .
   <option value="N">Nth location</option>
</select>
```

I have an unrelated click button that makes an API call which returns a location id.  The location ids correspond to the values in the SELECT list above.  As opposed to make a second API call to resolve the ID to a name how could I do something like the following in jQuery

```
 $("#LIST")[returned_id].html()
```

For example if the button returnd location id 2:

```
 $("#LIST")[2].html()
```

which should return "Chicago"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuerys selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to do the work for you - specifically, the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

> `jQuery('[attribute="value"]')`

So your code would need to look something like this -

```
var cityName = $('#LIST > option[value="'+ RETURNED_ID +'"').text();
```

Here we are saying that we want all the `<option>` tags with a value attribute equal to the value of `RETURNED_ID`.

Comment: Any difference in efficiency since you are using ">" unlike the answers bellow?

Comment: I like to be as specific as I can with my selectors - there will be people that say this is more efficient becuase jQuery doesn't need to look so hard...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attribute selector`. Try the following:

```
var txt = $('#LIST option[value='+ id +']').text()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var valueOfItemToChange=2
alert($("#LIST option[value='"+valueOfItemToChange+"']").text())
```

will alert the text of option with value 2

Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/EctGG/5/